# QTextEdit how to keep currently selected text line at the same position on the screen

Tags: qt, cursor-position, qtextedit

I want my text cursor to be always at the same vertical position of **QTextEdit**.

As an example lets say i have (*I* = cursor, ==== delimit the edit box). Lets say ***I*** is 20 pixels from top.

```
============================================
Today is a nice weather
I wanted to go *I*for a walk. 
But finaly got caught in a rain.
============================================
```

now if i move my cursor down.

```
============================================
I wanted to go for a walk. 
But finaly got *I*caught in a rain.
Damn it.
============================================
```

Not that i can not simply count lines from, because i have embedded tables and the font size is different too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manipulate directly the position of the scroll bars (`QTextEdit::verticalScrollBar()`) to keep the cursor position (`QTextEdit::cursorRect()`) relative to the window at the desired `targetYPosition`, by connecting the signal `cursorPositionChanged()` of the `QTextEdit` to a slot like this:

```
void moveScrollBar() {
    int cursorY = textEdit->cursorRect().top();
    QScrollBar *vbar = textEdit->verticalScrollBar();
    vbar->setValue(vbar->value() + cursorY - targetYPosition);
}
```