# QTextEdit how to keep currently selected text line at the same position on the screen in pyqt5

Tags: python

This has been answered in [QTextEdit how to keep currently selected text line at the same position on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830330/qtextedit-how-to-keep-currently-selected-text-line-at-the-same-position-on-the-s/9832270#9832270) but it is in c++ and it used a pointers (i guess?). My question is, how to do this exact same function in python?

This is my code:

```
def moveScrollBar(self):
        cursorPos = self.textLabel.cursorRect().top()               
        scrollbar = self.textLabel.verticalScrollBar()
        scrollbar.setValue(scrollbar.value() + cursorPos - 2)
        self.textLabel.setVerticalScrollbar(scrollbar)
```

notice that I added the last line thinking that it will make it work but instead it gave me back an error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QObject::valueChanged(int)
QObject::connect: No such signal QObject::rangeChanged(int,int)
```

the way i connected it to the cursorPositionChanged() is like so:

```
self.textLabel.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.moveScrollBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textLabel.setVerticalScrollbar(scrollbar)
```

is not possible because `setVerticalScrollbar` methode wants an int. So you could directly use

```
self.textLabel.setVerticalScrollbar(scrollbar.value() + cursorPos - 2)
```

instead of

```
scrollbar.setValue(scrollbar.value() + cursorPos - 2)
```

Be aware that `cursorPos` and the target position `-2` are in pixels. The target position could have been mischosen.

Comment: Hello sir! Thank you for respoding but the funtion definition of setVerticalScrollbar in QtWidgets.pyi is:
    def setVerticalScrollBar(self, scrollbar: 'QScrollBar') -> None: ...
so i think it didn't want an int as parameter